k8s's pod in EC2 get disabled every hours
I'm running k8s on my ec2(t3.medium, not eks node) as masternode for webapp.
I thought t3.medium could handle k8s, but.. my api server just not works(nginx shows 502 bad gateway) every hours and I think it happens if ec2 cpu load get over 30% ~40%
maybe tight cpu requests could be a problem..? but how do i adjust cpu limit or request?
k8s node cpu description

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
